File permissions problem with samba share on Ubuntu server
I have a samba server with one share running on Ubuntu Server 20.04. I can access this share find from my laptop, logged into the samba server as me. But if I run a process with sudo, which needs to access the samba server, it returns a "Permission denied" error. What do I need to change on the server, or in my process, to get it to work?
Here are the settings for the share in smb.conf:
[ourshare]
path = /srv/ourshare
valid users = me otheruser
force group = ourshare
browseable = no
guest ok = no
read only = no
create mask = 0660
force create mode = 0660
directory mask = 0770
force directory mode = 0770

Server directory permissions are as follows:
/srv: drwxr-xr-x   5 root root       4096 Mar 19  2023 srv
/srv/ourshare: drwxrws--- 9 nobody ourshare  4096 Apr 16 07:47 ourshare

As me, I can access the directory just fine from the command line using:
me@mylaptop:~$ cd /run/user/1000/gvfs/'smb-share:server=192.168.1.100'

But my script, which me runs using sudo, fails with "Permission denied" when it tries to access the same path using tar:
tar -cvf /home/me/backup.tar -T /home/me/file-list.txt

Where file-list.txt contains the line:
/run/user/1000/gvfs/'smb-share:server=192.168.1.100'

It also fails with "Permission denied" if me does sudo -s and then attempts to cd into the share.

/run/user/1000/gvfs is the parent folder for all gvfs fuse-based mounts and as such can only be traversed by the user that invoked it - uid=1000 in this case. Not even root can traverse that folder.
My suggestion is to not use gvfs to mount the share but cifs - as in mount.cifs
Make sure the cifs "helper" package is installed:
sudo apt install cifs-utils

Create a mount point for this remote share - you can't mount a server only it's share:
sudo mkdir /mnt/ourshare

Then mount the share to that mountpoint using cifs - something like this:
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.100/ourshare /mnt/ourshare -o username=me,password=xxx,uid=1000

Replace "me" and "xxx" with their correct values.

Worked. Thank you very much.

Samba, along with NFS, avoid a host of security vulnerabilities by remapping the remote root user to some "harmless" user (e.g. nobody) on the server.
